# I am using react-native-google-places-autocomplete to search for places and not able to configure for zip code

Tags: react-native

I have integrated https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete successfully and now need only to know how to get suggestions from zip-code . Example: When i write '35801' in search text-input, It should give me 'Huntsville, AL' in suggestions instead other all address, 'Huntsville, AL' should be prioritised

My autocomplete component

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
  placeholder='Search'
  minLength={2}
  autoFocus={false}
  returnKeyType={'search'}
  keyboardAppearance={'light'}
  listViewDisplayed={false}
  fetchDetails={true}
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
  renderDescription={row => row.description}
  onPress={(data, details = null) => {
    console.log(data,details);
    this.setState({location:data.structured_formatting.main_text, user_long:details.geometry.location.lng, user_lat: details.geometry.location.lat })
  }}
  enablePoweredByContainer={false}
  getDefaultValue={() => ''}
  textInputProps={{
    ref: (input) => {this.fourthTextInput = input}
  }}
  query={{
    // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
    key: 'api-key',
    language: 'en',
    region: "US", //It removes the country name from the suggestion list
    types: '', // default: 'geocode'
    components: 'country:us'
  }}
  styles={{
    container: {width:width/1.4}
    textInputContainer: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      margin: 0,
      width: width / 1.4,
      padding:0,
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      borderBottomWidth:0
    },
    textInput: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      minWidth: width/1.4, 
      borderColor: "#cbb4c0",
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      color: '#5d5d5d',
      fontSize: 14,
    },
    description: {
      color:'#ac879a',
      fontWeight: '300'
    },
    predefinedPlacesDescription: {
      color: '#1faadb'
    }
  }}
  currentLocation={false} 
  nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
  GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{// available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
  }}
  GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
    // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
    rankby: 'distance',
    type: 'cafe'
  }}    
  GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{
    // available options for GooglePlacesDetails API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details
    fields: 'formatted_address',
  }}
  filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']}
  debounce={200}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The zipcode or postal code is found inside "details" returned from the onPress event.

It'll actually be inside an array of objects (address_components) inside  it.

The thing is that its position can vary.

The best way I found was to iterate this array looking for the type "postal_code".

Here is what has worked for me:

```
const [postalCode, setPostalCode] = useState("")

return (
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        placeholder='Search'

        onPress={(data, details) => {

            for (let i = 0; i < details.address_components.length; i++) {
               
                if (details.address_components[i].types[0] === "postal_code") {
                    setPostalCode(details.address_components[i].long_name)
                }

            }
        }}
        
        enablePoweredByContainer={false}
        fetchDetails={true}
        onFail={(error) => console.log("Error at finding location: ", error)}
        query={{
            key: googleKey,
            language: "en",
        }}
    />
)
```

***Edited in 08/07/21***

Another option is to split the string received on details.formatted_address.

This might be easier.

I hope it hepls!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the '(region)' type in the query prop.

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
    placeholder="Search"
    onPress={(data, details = null) => {
      // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
      console.log(data, details);
    }}
    query={{
      key: GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY,
      language: "en", // language of the results
      types: "(regions)",
    }}
  />
```

If you are looking to only search within a specific country use:

```
query={{
      key: GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY,
      language: "en", // language of the results
      types: "(regions)",
      components: "country:us",
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function extraireInformations(adresse) {
  const regexRue = /<span class="street-address">(.*?)<\/span>/;
  const regexCodePostal = /<span class="postal-code">(.*?)<\/span>/;
  const regexLocalite = /<span class="locality">(.*?)<\/span>/;
  const regexPays = /<span class="country-name">(.*?)<\/span>/;

  const rue = adresse.match(regexRue)[1];
  const codePostal = adresse.match(regexCodePostal)[1];
  const localite = adresse.match(regexLocalite)[1];
  const pays = adresse.match(regexPays)[1];

  const informations = {
    localite: localite,
    rue: rue,
    pays: pays,
    codePostal: codePostal,
  };

  return informations;
}

<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
    placeholder="Search"
    onPress={(data, details = null) => {
     const address = extraireInformations(details?.adr_address);
     console.log(address)
    }}
    query={{
      key: GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY,
      language: "en",
    }}
  />
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**