# Google places api not returning postal code?

Tags: react-native, google-api, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I'm creating an ecommerce app and we need the postal code to calculate shipping costs, using address autocomplete from google place api, not sure if it's a limitation from the api, but it doesn't return a postal code.
I'm using https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete for the autocomplete.

I looked through google docs as well, and it doesn't mention anything about it.

Just wondering if there's a way to get a postal code from an address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google autocomplete API does not return a postal code as part of its results.

The package you mentioned has a `fetchDetails` props, which will call the Google Places API to get more information including the postal code.  You can then access the data from `details` in `onPress`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';

const GooglePlacesInput = () => {
  return (
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      placeholder='Search'
      fetchDetails={true}
      onPress={(data, details) => {
        console.log('data: ', data);
        console.log('details: ', details);
      }}
      query={{
        key: 'YOUR API KEY',
        language: 'en',
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default GooglePlacesInput;
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me when I iterate through the array of objects (address_components) inside details, as you can see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68553851/14608654